# Duda Interfaces swing Java

Tags: java, java-swing

les comentó mi situación. Estoy creando una interfaz sencilla en Java, por lo cual creé un botón que lee los datos ingresados, por ello use el método actionperformed de ActionListener, sin embargo, no puedo almacenarlos en ninguna parte. Entiendo que es porque el método es void, así que no puede retornar nada, así como también las variables son solo visibles para el método en cuestión.

¿Hay alguna solución a esto?
Deseo que esos valores obtenidos de esos TextField sean argumentos del constructor de la clase TabCalc, pero me dice que no han sido inicializados.

¿Alguna idea? ¡Gracias!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame{

    JTextField JTPbm = new JTextField();

    public void init(){

        //Paneles

        JPanel Frame1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel Buttons = new JPanel();
        JPanel Principal = new JPanel();

        JLabel JLName = new JLabel("Nombre");
        JLabel JLPbm = new JLabel("PBM");
        JLabel JLYears = new JLabel("Año");

        JTextField JTName = new JTextField();

        TabCalc TableR = new TabCalc();

        JComboBox<String> Years = new JComboBox<>();
        Years.addItem("");
        Years.addItem("2019");
        Years.addItem("2020");
        Years.addItem("2021");
        Years.addItem("2022");
        Years.addItem("2023");
        Years.addItem("2024");

        JTPbm.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){
            
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){
                try {
                    Integer PBMd = Integer.parseInt(JTPbm.getText());
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame1, "¡Ingresa un PBM válido!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    JTPbm.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        JButton Butt_OK = new JButton("Enviar");

        Butt_OK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String PBM_got = JTPbm.getText();
                String Year_got = Years.getSelectedItem().toString(); 

                if(PBM_got.equals("") || Year_got.equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Principal, "¡Información incompleta!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    if(Integer.parseInt(PBM_got) > 100 || Integer.parseInt(PBM_got) <= 0){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Principal, "¡Información errónea!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }else{

                    DBConnect sql = new DBConnect(PBM_got,Year_got);
                    ArrayList<Object> s = sql.ConnectDB();
                    boolean  x = (boolean) s.get(0);
                    if(x == true){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Principal, "¡La consulta fue exitosa!", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }}
        });

        String PBM_got = "23"; //Necesito obtener PBM_got y Year_got del actionListener
        String Year_got = "2023";

        TableR.TabFill(PBM_got, Year_got);

        JButton Butt_del = new JButton("Borrar");
        Butt_del.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JTName.setText("");
                JTPbm.setText("");
            }
        });

        Buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,2,5));
        Buttons.add(Butt_OK);
        Buttons.add(Butt_del);

        Frame1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,5,2));
        Frame1.add(JLName);
        Frame1.add(JTName);
        Frame1.add(JLPbm);
        Frame1.add(JTPbm);
        Frame1.add(JLYears);
        Frame1.add(Years);

        Principal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Principal.add(Frame1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Principal.add(Buttons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        Principal.add(TableR,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(Principal);

        setTitle("Calculadora de matrícula");
        setSize(400, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui1 = new GUI();
        gui1.init();
    }
}
```

Comment: es un problema del ámbito de variables, las variables no existen en el ámbito en que las quieres llamar. intenta pasar esa última linea dos lineas antes

Comment: Observa que tus componentes son accesibles a pesar de no estar declarados dentro de `ActionPerformed`, es por que fueron declarados en un ámbito mayor; podrías hacer lo mismo con tus variables, pero muchas veces no tiene caso "bajar" el valor de un atributo de un objeto a una variable, en otras palabras, dices *"no puedo almacenarlos"* cuando realmente ya están almacenados -en el componente-.

Comment: @Sal, intenté declararlos como atributos de la clase, pero cuando los ingreso como parámetros de un método, tipo metodo1(String PBM_got, String Year_got) me aparece la aclaración de que esas variables no han sido inicializadas. Por lo que entiendo, no estarían tomando los valores de las mismas que se encuentran en el método de actionPerformed. :'(

Comment: Basta con inicializarlas con `null` en la declaración.

Comment: @Sal, lo intenté y los parámetros que se pasan al método que necesito ahora son null, no toma los que están en el método del actionListener. :'(

Comment: ¿Cuál *"método que necesito"*? ¿Dónde y cómo está declarado? y ¿Dónde lo invocas?.

Comment: @Sal, ya lo edité, sorry. Lo que pasa es que esos datos (PBM_got, Year_got) que son obtenidos por la interfaz necesito "almacenarlos" para enviarlos como parámetros a un constructor, en este caso, de la clase TabCalc.

Comment: Exacto, justo lo que le dije, un problema del ámbito de variables

Comment: @MarcePuente, lo acabo de hacer: String PBM_got; String Year_got; después del JButton y antes de addActionListener, y he dejado únicamente dentro del actionPerformed la asignación PBM_got = JTPbm.getText() y lo mimso con Year_got. Sin embargo, me dice: Local variable PBM_got defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively finalJava(536871575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

Dado que el problema surge por un problema de "scope", para agregar un escuchador, creamos una clase, y si bien desde una clase hija, se pueden ver los atributos de la clase padre, no se puede ver una variable que está dentro de un método (por ejemplo, el constructor).

Una posibilidad, quitamos el código que está dentro del "listener", y agregamos una llamada a un método auxiliar, en el que vamos a ejecutar el código.

```
class Gui {

    public Gui() {
        // blablabla
        JButton Butt_OK = new JButton( "Enviar" );
        Butt_OK.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
              ejecutar();
           }
        });
    }

    void ejecutar() {
       String PBM_got = JTPbm.getText();
       String Year_got = Years.getSelectedItem().toString();
    
       if( PBM_got.equals( "" ) ) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Principal, "¡Información incompleta!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
       }
       else {
          if( Integer.parseInt( PBM_got ) > 100 || Integer.parseInt( PBM_got ) <= 0 ) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Principal, "¡Información errónea!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
          }
          else {
    
             DBConnect sql = new DBConnect( PBM_got, Year_got );
             ArrayList<Object> s = sql.ConnectDB();
             boolean x = (boolean) s.get( 0 );
             if( x == true ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Principal, "¡La consulta fue existosa!", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
             }
          }         
       }
       TabCalc TableR = new TabCalc( PBM_got, Year_got );
    }
}
```

Otro camino es:
Declaramos las variables como atributos de la clase, por lo que se transforman en globales (incluso para la clase hija).

```
class Gui {

   String PBM_got;
   String Year_got;

   public Gui() {
      // blablabla
      JButton Butt_OK = new JButton( "Enviar" );
      Butt_OK.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            PBM_got = JTPbm.getText();
            Year_got = Years.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if( PBM_got.equals( "" ) ) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Principal, "¡Información incompleta!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }
            else {
               if( Integer.parseInt( PBM_got ) > 100 || Integer.parseInt( PBM_got ) <= 0 ) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Principal, "¡Información errónea!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
               }
               else {
                  DBConnect sql = new DBConnect( PBM_got, Year_got );
                  ArrayList<Object> s = sql.ConnectDB();
                  boolean x = (boolean) s.get( 0 );
                  if( x == true ) {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Principal, "¡La consulta fue existosa!", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

A mi me gusta más la primer solución, porque declaro el método en otra clase, y mantengo separada la interfaz gráfica del código, por otro lado, si como creo tus variables son de corta vida, no aseguramos que el recolector de basura se encargue de ellas.

Comment: El tema es que he creado más botones, y están fuera de ese método del actionListener de ese botón, entonces esos métodos que proporcionaste estarían todavía dentro del método del actionListener y lo necesito afuera para poder crear un JPanel y añadirlo al panel principal. :'c

Comment: El método **ejecutar** está en la clase padre, no dentro del **listener**,  pero si no te sirve, declaras las variables como atributos, y accedes desde el **listener** (segundo ejemplo), sino, sube el código que necesitas ejecutar y lo vemos.

Comment: Ya lo actualicé. Mmm, lo que pretendo es, el botón de OK, si verifica que los campos no están vacíos, entonces los campos que se registraron pasa a un método que crea una tabla para que se pueda agregar al frame principal. Y este es el problema, extraer esos datos por fuera del actionListener. Es lo que deseo hacer. :)

Comment: Ya que le respondes podrías indicar que en Java los nombres de las variables deben seguir una convención denominada camelCase. No es `Year_got` es `yearGot`. No es `PBM_got`, es `pbmGot`. Lo mismo se aplica a los nombres de los métodos y al resto de cosas, excepto constantes que van todo en mayúsculas con guiones bajos (`private static final String SOY_UNA_CONSTANTE = "es una constante";`) y los nombres de clase que van en PascalCase, que es lo mismo que el camelCase pero empezando en mayúscula.

Comment: @Benito-B, gracias por la aclaración. :)

Comment: @Benito-B, el estilo de codificación a usar, **es una elección personal** (la palabra "estilo", debería ayudarte a entender), el funcionamiento de un programa, no se ve afectado por el mismo.

Comment: @MarcePuente Y tú puedes usar el estilo que quieras en tus proyectos personales, pero la industria está altamente estandarizada y aprender esos estándares y estilos cuando estás aprendiendo la base es más fácil que aprender a hacerlo de otra manera y luego tener que *reaprender* a hacerlo según los estándares que aplica todo el mundo. Así que... tu elección es tuya, pero en Java programamos con camelCase y PascalCase, no snake_case. Las convcenciones, estándares y buenas prácticas se crearon para algo, y especialmente a la hora de compartir código con los demás, ayudan mucho.